# Can I use | as column separator in pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I want to use `|` as column separator in the CSV file. Because it looks clean, so I won't feel headache to edit the CSV file directly.

I have checked the manual, it seems the option `col sep` accepts only a few values: `comma` for `,`, `semicolon` for `;`, `colon` for `:`, `braces` for `{}`, `ampersand` for `&`, space and tab. That's all.

I have tried `col sep=|` however it won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the code, the separator choices are hard-coded (they set an internal switch, which then selects different auxiliaries). You should be able to read the table described using [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool), or could make a feature request for `pgfplots`.

To do things 'by hand' I think you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\let\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@PIPE
\long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@#1{%
  \pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE#1|\pgfplotstable@EOI}%
\long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@PIPE#1|{%
    \pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@{#1}%
    \pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: +1 for the magical code. It's just not compiled: `\long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##: ! Parameters must be numbered consecutively.`. I've made the feature request: http://goo.gl/B8hl0

Comment: @XièJìléi I've corrected that: I took some code from `pgfplots` and forget it was in a nested definition.